# How to modify the turtlebot robot model in rviz?

Tags: ros, rviz, urdf, robot-model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have remodeled my turtlebot with additional hardware to increase the height of the kinect location. I would like to model the same in rviz. I want to know which urdf file i should edit in order to do this. Any help here is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28735/how-to-modify-the-turtlebot-robot-model-in-rviz?/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2012-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The URDF file for the turtlebot is in the ros package `turtlebot_description`. It is loaded on the parameter server in `turtlebot_bringup/minimal.launch`. Please note that the package `turtlebot_description` will be read only. The best way to change it is to copy and rename it (make sure that you get the includes right in turtlebot.xacro).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) on 2014-04-19**:
Hi Lorenz, I cannot find turtlebot.xacro in Groovy. I'm using turtlebot2. I can find only turtlebot.urdf.xacro, and I'm confusing in rvizing it? Pls help me, thanks!